# Issue with adding ROLE_ASSISTANT

Tags: android, google-assistant

Now that Android 10 & above has this feature, I'm trying to add it. Included this in the manifest:

```
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST"/>
```

And here's the code:

```
mRM = (RoleManager) mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.ROLE_SERVICE); 
bAvailable = mRM.isRoleAvailable(RoleManager.ROLE_ASSISTANT);

    if (bAvailable) {
        roleIntent = mRM.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_ASSISTANT);
        
        startActivityForResult (roleIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

But, I keep getting this error:

```
RequestRoleActivity: Role is not requestable: android.app.role.ASSISTANT
RequestRoleFragment: Role request result requestingUid=10021 requestingPackageName=com.broadcom.BcmMicCapture roleName=android.app.role.ASSISTANT qualifyingCount=-1 currentUid=-1 currentPackageName=null grantedAnotherUid=-1 grantedAnotherPackageName=null result=1
```

Any idea what's amiss here? Is it a sepolicy issue? Or the app needs to add some other permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible anymore.

Google made this role not requestable:

https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/packages/modules/Permission/+/3512ea1e5dd8b91f0017dfdb523b3421f7b165e2